# mitmproxy as a reverse proxy - force SSL?

Tags: mitmproxy

> Say you have some toy project that should get SSL support. Simply set up mitmproxy as a reverse proxy on port 443 and you’re done (mitmdump -p 443 --mode reverse:http://localhost:80/). Mitmproxy auto-detects TLS traffic and intercepts it dynamically.

https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/

Can you have mitmdump enforce SSL? Or verify that the client really uses SSL?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a mitmproxy addon that checks just that:

```py
from mitmproxy import http

def request(flow):
    if not flow.client_conn.tls_established:
        flow.request.response = http.HTTPResponse.make(400)
```